# HTML alphabetical ordered list with 'ch' and 'ñ'

Tags: html

I need to rewrite a website that have some content with ordered lists like:

```
a) blablabla
b) blablabla
c) blablabla
ch) ¿How can I do this?
d) ...
...
n)
ñ) ¿And this too? Its a Ñ
o) ...
```

I want to do that automatically with HTML+CSS, preferibly. I don't care if I must use some JS, but I want to know if thats possible with current HTML+CSS standards (I don't find anything like this).

And no, I can't change that numeration schema.

Comment: how about using <pre>. as that will let you type the content as it is is without applying any formatting

Comment: Right now the website content is in a big <pre> tag, and its veeery ugly and difficult to read... The website collects laws so, all the content is in a big "old spanish alphabetical ordered list" (and thats why I can't change the numeration schema).

Comment: then I do not see a way out with my limited knowledge. All the best for any solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
var alphabetical = ["a", "c", "nie", "ch","z"];
alphabetical.sort();
for (var i=0; i<alphabetical.length; i++) {
    var sorted = alphabetical[i];
    var inner=sorted.replace('nie','ñ');
    //example
    document.body.innerHTML+=inner;
}
```